# Ordenar objetos en un array de PHP según clave numérica

Tags: php, poo

estoy ejercitando POO en PHP y ahora tengo que ordenar los objetos de un array que envió a través de formulario _POST y deben estar ordenados basados en la clave numérica de cada uno de estos objetos. La clave numérica es una propiedad de la clase. Buscando en este foro, en el de ingles y en otros sitios me encontré con dos posibilidades de solucionarlos que mas me convencieron pero no logre que me funcionaran y son la función array_multisort y una que leí de un usuario de acá. Es esta:

```
function object_sorter($codigo,$orden=null) {
return function ($a, $b) use ($codigo,$orden) {
      $result=  ($orden=="DESC") ? strnatcmp($b->$codigo, $a->$codigo) :  strnatcmp($a->$codigo, $b->$codigo);
      return $result;
};
}

 usort($_SESSION['art'], object_sorter('clave','DESC'));
```

Esto último me funcionaba si cambiaba la clave numérica en la clase y la ponía en public en vez de private pero no sé si seria lo correcto.

En fin, alguien conoce una forma para poder ordenar los objetos del array utilizando la clave numérica?

Dejo aquí por si es necesario la clase

```
class Producto{

private $clave;
private $descripcion;
private $precio;
private $stock;

public function __construct($clave, $descripcion, $precio, $stock){
    $this->clave = $clave;
    $this->descripcion = $descripcion;
    $this->precio = $precio;
    $this->stock = $stock;
}
public function setClave($clave){
    $this->clave = $clave;
}
public function getClave(){
    return $this->clave;
}
public function setDescripcion($descripcion){
    $this->descripcion = $descripcion;
}
public function getDescripcion(){
    return $this->descripcion;
}
public function setPrecio($precio){
    $this->precio = $precio;
}
public function getPrecio(){
    return $this->precio;
}
public function setStock($stock){
    $this->stock = $stock;
}
public function getStock(){
    return $this->stock;
}

  }
 ?>
```

y también esta parte del objeto y el arreglo por si las dudas

```
$oproducto = new Producto($_POST["clave"], $_POST["descripcion"], $_POST["precio"], $_POST["stock"]);
    $_SESSION["art"][]= $oproducto;
```

Saludos y gracias por leer hasta acá.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema concretamente? No tienes que cambiar la propiedad de `private` a `public`, sino usar el *getter*  de la clase para obtenerla, que para eso está.

Comment: Discúlpame, el problema es mi inexperiencia realmente. Desde que empece con lo de poo que busco, busco y al final siempre termino preguntando cosas que seguro me podria dar cuenta si fuera mas capaz ¿En que parte del código tendría que poner el getter?

Comment: En la pregunta no se ve con claridad el contexto. Allí donde decías que te exigía una propiedad pública del objeto puedes usar el getter en vez de la propiedad del objeto. O sea, si estabas pasando algo como: `$elObjeto->clave`,  tendrías que cambiarlo por `$elObjeto->getClave()` Si observas, el método `getClave()` del objeto sí es público, y por eso lo puedes llamar desde fuera... ese es el propósito precisamente, declarar las propiedades como privadas y definir métodos para obtenerlas, de modo que las mismas no puedan ser modificadas directamente. Son cosas que irás aprendiendo con paciencia

Answer (score 0):

En PHP 7 puedes usar el operador *nave espacial*, prácticamente es una línea de código:

```
usort( $_SESSION['art']
     , function($a, $b){ 
          return $a->getClave() <=> $b->getClave(); 
       }
     );
```